# NextAuth.js signout if Apollo GraphQL token is invalid or it has expired

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js, apollo, next-auth

What would it be the best way to clear the NextAuth.js session when trying to hit the backend (Apollo GraphQL) and it returns a 401 because the token has expired or is invalid?

I thought about an `errorLink` and `signout`, but as far as I know `signout` cannot be used server side at `getServerSideProps`, but only client-side.

What is the recommended way to do so? Is there any other way to implement a middleware to take care of that scenario?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide us a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I've added the errorLink I'm trying to use, but as I said `signOut()` is only available client-side.

Answer (score 4):

signOut() clears the session by clearing the state in client side , here what you can do is to check from backend if the state exists and if it is not then do something instead of 401(Unauthorized).
Hope You Read It: https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#signout

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which version of Apollo you are using, but assuming you are using Apollo 3.0 <= you can create a setcontext for your requests.

```js
import { setContext } from '@apollo/client/link/context';

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  const token = session?.accessToken ? session.accessToken : ""
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
    }
  }
});

function createApolloClient(session) {
  return new ApolloClient({
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    ssrMode: typeof window === 'undefined',
    link: from([
      authLink,
      errorLink,
      createUploadLink({
        uri: GRAPHQL_URI,
        credentials: 'same-origin'
      }),
    ]),
  });
}
```

Since signOut() rerenders your app you can check the context to see whether it has a valid token on the request from your server. Haven't tested this, but in theory this is how I might implement it.